# Is recurrent simulator training required every 12 months whilst acting as SIC under Part 91?

Tags: faa-regulations, crew, currency

What are the regulations on recurrent training for a crew member who is type rated as PIC but is acting as SIC, flying internationally on a Bombardier Global Express Part 91 operation (not subpart K)? The last recurrent training for the crew member was 18 months ago.

Part 61.55 stipulates SIC qualifications but i would like to know if recurrent simulator training is required every 12 months whilst acting as SIC? If not, then what 'currency' values are required to maintain your privileges as SIC?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Is this a Part 91 Subpart K operation?

Comment: No not a sub part k operation

Answer (score 1):

The only Part 91 recurrent training and testing requirements are in [subpart K](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&sid=3efaad1b0a259d4e48f1150a34d1aa77&rgn=div5&view=text&node=14:2.0.1.3.10&idno=14#sp14.2.91.k), so if they don't apply to you then only the general currency requirements in Part 61 would apply.

The [SIC currency requirements in 61.55](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_155) are (every 12 months):

> (1) Become familiar with the following information for the specific
>   type aircraft for which second-in-command privileges are requested—
>
> (i) Operational procedures applicable to the powerplant, equipment,
>   and systems.
>
> (ii) Performance specifications and limitations.
>
> (iii) Normal, abnormal, and emergency operating procedures.
>
> (iv) Flight manual.
>
> (v) Placards and markings.
>
> (2) Except as provided in paragraph (g) of this section, performed and
>   logged pilot time in the type of aircraft or in a flight simulator
>   that represents the type of aircraft for which second-in-command
>   privileges are requested, which includes—
>
> (i) Three takeoffs and three landings to a full stop as the sole
>   manipulator of the flight controls;
>
> (ii) Engine-out procedures and maneuvering with an engine out while
>   executing the duties of pilot in command; and
>
> (iii) Crew resource management training.

Practically speaking, what the FAA requires is only part of the picture because your insurance company will probably mandate certain training and currency requirements that may go well beyond the regulations.